# XSD validation in a sequence and choice

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I looked at many posts without finding my answer...

I have a XSD to validate my XML and I encounter some issue.

Here (part of) my XSD

```
<xsd:group name="Element">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element ref="El1" />
            <xsd:element ref="El2" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>

<xsd:element name="Tree">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="El3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:group ref="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

It works fine, but this is not entirely what I want to do. I would like a schema more like this :

```
<xsd:element name="Tree">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:group ref="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="El3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:group ref="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

but this schema is wrong.

What I'd like is an unsorted list of El1 or El2 with optionnaly one (and only one) El3.

Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into the 'unique particle attribution' trap of XSD (which corresponds to the 'determinism' trap of XML DTDs and the 'non-ambiguity' trap of SGML DTDs).  XSD won't accept your content model because when it encounters an instance of element El1 as the first child of a Tree elements, there is no way of telling without lookahead whether it matches the first reference to the group Element or the second.  (Don't ask why anyone in the responsible WGs thought it was important to tell this; it's a tedious and depressing story.)

So you need a slight variation in your declaration:

```
<xsd:element name="Tree">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:group ref="Element" 
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xsd:element ref="El3"/>
        <xsd:group ref="Element" 
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like is an unsorted list of El1 or El2 with optionnaly one (and only one) El3.

I read that as

(e1 | e2)* (e3, (e1 | e2)*)?

that is

```
sequence 
  choice max=unbounded
    E1
    E2
  /choice
  sequence min=0
    E3
    choice max=unbounded
      E1
      E2
    /choice
  /sequence
/sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, I slightly modified your proposal with a choice indicator around the second sequence :

```
<xsd:element name="Tree">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:group ref="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
         <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
           <xsd:element ref="El3"/>
           <xsd:group ref="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
           <xsd:element ref="El4" minOccurs="0"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element ref="El4"/>
      </xsd:choice> 
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

as I had still a 'unique particle attribution' error with a fourth element.

Thanks again !

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce that result.  Once the maxOccurs="0" on the new xsd:choice element is corrected to minOccurs="0" (on the assumption that you don't really want minOccurs="1" and maxOccurs="0", which is what you now have), there is no error in this declaration.

Comment: Of course, as you noticed, you had to change maxOccurs by minOccurs in the choice indicator. Thanks for the remark, the post has been edited.